# Exposing a full (C language) pthread interface from a C++ library based on c++0x std::thread

Tags: c++, c, c++11, pthreads

Is it conceptually possible to write a small wrapper library based on `std::thread` (and perhaps other C++0x parts) that exposes the full pthread interface to a C program?

(If you're wondering how this could be useful: in the hypothetical world where a mainstream OS kernel was written in C++ with a fully C++0x compliant Standard library attached to it, this would be an issue that comes up, because the kernel I'm talking/thinking about does not expose a C interface, only a C Standard library, based on its "native" C++ "backend")

Comment: @JackN: I fail to see the use of marking both questions as duplicates of each other.

Comment: @JackN, @André: while they are specifically about a different topic (!).

Comment: @JackN: How is this a duplicate of that question?

Comment: Maybe, but the intent would be clearer if this was a single question.

Comment: Is it not already exposed via the pthread library?

Comment: @Martin: at least on Windows, the pthread library is  wrapper for OS threads. And GCC's std::thread isn't yet available on Windows. I don't know how it is on Linux, but I'd think there is some OS/kernel level interaction required.

Comment: +1, and I deleted my comment. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, such an implementation should be possible. I even wrote a simple version at one point, just to prove I could.

There are a few things which are tricky, but most stuff (e.g. mutexes, condition variables, threads) would be a simple wrapper.

Asynchronous cancellation is one of the tricky things --- it requires support from the OS to interrupt a thread asynchronously, so true asynchronous cancellation cannot be written on top of "pure" C++0x threads. Of course, you could just delay cancellation to a cancellation point anyway, though as R points out this would be a low quality implementation of the feature.

Answer (score 1):

IIRC, there is at least the asynchronous cancellation which has no equivalent in C++0X thread library.

Comment: Several implementations (e.g. PlayStation 3) simply avoid pthread_cancel(), so I think it's legitimate to avoid it.

Comment: Indeed, POSIX reads "When cancelability is enabled and the cancelability type is PTHREAD_CANCEL_ASYNCHRONOUS (as defined in <pthread.h>), new or pending cancellation requests **may be acted upon** at any time." (emphasis added by me). I think this means a conformant implementation could treat asynchronous cancellation the same as deferred.

Comment: Of course, one could argue that such an implementations sucks, since a major (extremely clean!) use of asynchronous cancellation is to cancel long-running mathematical computations which contain no library function calls. One could of course insert `pthread_testcancel` calls periodically, but that may be undesirable in library code that's pure C and not dependent on POSIX.

Answer (score 1):

In [libc++](http://libcxx.llvm.org/) there is:

```
class thread
{
public:
    // ...
    typedef pthread_t native_handle_type;
    native_handle_type native_handle();
    // ...
};
```

native_handle_type and native_handle() are conditionally supported.  That is, they don't have to be there.  However, if they are there, and if it is based on pthreads, then doing what you want to do is why this hook is there.

Comment: the pthread library is more than just a `native_handle_type` IMHO.

Comment: @rubenvb: Right, it's a library. Use the instance of `native_handle_type` to make calls to that library. Wrap these calls in a bunch of exposed functions if you like. Seems odd though: your "manual" calls could conflict with the functionality of `std::thread`. Trying to hack out abstraction like this seems dangerous.

Comment: @Tomalak: I think you misunderstand my intent: I'm not trying to port the existing pthread library as it exists for unix and win32 (pthreads-win32). I'm trying (hypothetically) to provide the same interface *only* built from OS/kernel specific C++ functions and classes, as there is no other possible kernel interface to implement user threads in. pthreads is in itself implemented in OS threads (at least this is the case in Windows)

Comment: @rubenvb: Yea, that's what I was talking about.

Comment: My answer is evidently unclear.  I'm trying to communicate that if std::thread doesn't give you everything you want, and you're aware of the underlying OS (such as pthreads), then you can gain access to it via native_handle and thus extend the C++ interface of std::thread in your wrapper.  Other types in Chapter 30 (e.g. mutex, condition_variable) may also offer the native_handle() "escape hatch" in a similar fashion.

Comment: @Howard: I ee what you mean. Thanks for the clarification.